# Trying to use opencv with python on mac os x 10.6

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use the openCV libraries.
After lots of reading and lots of trial and error I decided to ask here.

I installed the openCV with macports, still I keep getting the same error (as I did when installing using the setup.py file inside openCV pkg).
My script is a "Hello world" script I wrote (copied) from http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv
and the "import cv" is not working. Is that because of path?
I tried adding:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('/opt/local/include/opencv')
```

but no change...

Thanks,
Yonathan

the full script is:

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow('a_window', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
image = cv.LoadImage('picture.png', cv.LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)

font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 3, 8) 

x = 200
y = 200

cv.PutText(frame,"Hello World!!!", (x,y),font, 255) 

cv.ShowImage('a_window', image)

cv.Waitkey(10000)
cv.SaveImage('image.png', image)
```

Comment: Could you add the complete error message that you get?

Comment: what's the error message? Does it tell you the line#?

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble getting the Python OpenCV bindings to work with a MacPorts OpenCV installation.

But, I got OpenCV installed on a mac using Homebrew, and I can `import cv` and `import cv2` in Python.

I [installed Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation), then did `brew install opencv`, and then everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

If installing via MacPorts make sure that you add the python variant when you install.

```
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

Then make sure that you are running the MacPorts version of python (usually /opt/local/bin/python2.7), not the default OSX version.